# Why my code is throwing this error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, c#-4.0

Getting this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime dtOldOpeningDateTime = (lblOldOpeningDate.Text+" "+lblOldOpeningTime.Text).ToDate();
```

`lblOpeningDate.Text` contains `26-03-2017` and `lblOldOpeningTime.Text` contains `02:00:00`.

Why this error ?

Update: toDate() function is like this:

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object obj)
{
    return Convert.ToDateTime(obj);
}
```

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - not really the same, as there is no explicit format string involved.

Comment: What is the culture this code is running under? The runtime is trying to parse the string using that culture, so if there is a mismatch, you will get that error.

Comment: Your code is working with that string http://rextester.com/SHBOAM56571 . Check textBox values

Comment: @S.Petrosov Sir, I checked but same error and the values i provided are the same

Comment: @S.Petrosov - that completely depends on the default culture when the code is running.

Comment: @DigiFriend what's the solution then ?

Comment: There's an overload to `Convert.ToDateTime` that takes an `IFormatProvider`, this can be any culture, such as `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @DigiFriend I tried overloading with this but same error

Comment: DateTime dtOldOpeningDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime((lblOldOpeningDate.Text + " " + lblOldOpeningTime.Text), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: I was just giving an example. You need to use a culture where the date separator is `-`. I don't know what culture that would be.

Comment: I also used  DateTime dtOldOpeningDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact((lblOldOpeningDate.Text + " " + lblOldOpeningTime.Text), "dd/MMM/yyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

but no luck

Comment: `MMM` is not the correct string.  Check the docs.